# How to apply market basket analysis / association rule in QlikView?

Tags: associations, pattern-matching, analytics, qlikview, market-basket-analysis

I want to use Association rule in Qlikview to find out the best product combination.
But Im not technically strong in QlikView. Can anyone provide tutorials or can kindly teach me how to use the features in qlikview to performed the association rule.(Time slice is flexible if possible. )

And now currently , I'm trying with this tutorial for Market Basket analysis

[ http://www.quickqlearqool.nl/?p=965 ]

But it did not count the number of customer for the same purchase behaviour . (within 1 month )

Data I have :

Order table:

Order_ID |
Order_date |
Product_ID |
customer_ID |
Quantity

Product table:

Product_ID |
Product Name

The following dropBox link is a sample datasets

[ https://www.dropbox.com/s/mu1bz1wbrojou4t/AssociationRule.zip ]

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Dropbox link doesn't work..

Comment: How would be the calculation? Can you provide more details..

Comment: And please add the dataset inline. That makes using it easier.

Comment: @ralfbecher sorry, may I know what calculation are you referring too? I want to find out the best product mixed for example customer buy A and within 1 month , the customer come back and purchase B . so I want to do a count on the number of customer who has the same purchase behaviour.So that I would be able what are the best product mix.

Comment: The only thing I can see with less effort is to make a chart to count all cominations:
dynamic Dimension: 
=aggr(Concat(DISTINCT product_id,'+',product_id), customer_id)
Expression:
=count(DISTINCT customer_id)

Comment: But this will give you not all possible combinations. Therefor a very complex script loop would be needed..

Comment: @ralfbecher Hi, can you kindly help me with this question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796426/venn-diagram-in-qlikview-to-display-relationship-for-product-mixed