# Market Basket Analysis model (Confidence & support )in Qlikview

Tags: modeling, qlikview, market-basket-analysis

Currently I have follow this tutorial for Market Basket analysis

[ http://www.quickqlearqool.nl/?p=965] ,But in market basket analysis it need model to support the analysis which is confidence and support . How to determine the support and confidence in qlikview to support my Market basket analysis?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply market basket analysis / association rule in QlikView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728735/how-to-apply-market-basket-analysis-association-rule-in-qlikview)

Comment: @i_saw_drones hi, thanks for reply. but it is 2 different question. the link that you gave it do not require confidence and support.